# Help with solve of Differential Equation from lines of curvature

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature

I was resolving a problem from Do Carmo, where I need to calculate the curvature lines of a helicoid. By the last part, what I got is:
$$
u'+ \sqrt{v^2 + c^2} = v'.
$$
I've tried to integrate in relation to $u$ first and got this:
$$
u\sqrt{v^2 + c^2} - M_{1} = uv'.
$$
When I integrate in $v$, this appears:
$$
u\left(\frac{1}{2}v\sqrt{v^2+c^2} + \frac{c^2}{2}\log{\left(\frac{\left|v + \sqrt{c^2 + v^2} \right|}{|c|}\right)} + M_{2}\right) - \lambda v + M_{3} = vu + M_{4},
$$
where $M_{i}$ are constants. How to prove that this equation is equivalent to
$$
\log{\left(v + \sqrt{v^2 + c^2} \right)} \pm u = \pm M,
$$
where $M$ is a constant? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure that there is an addition on the left side? The reference solution gives $u'\sqrt{c^2+v^2}=v'$, which is separable.

Comment: You mean lines of curvature of a *helicoid*?

Comment: Lutz is correct. There's also a $\pm$ missing.

Comment: Thank you all, that makes sense.